# remove two columns from a log file

Tags: regex, sed, awk, grep, cut

The command `lastlog` returns four fields such as `Username`, `Port`, `From` and  `Latest`.

For example.

```
$ lastlog
Username         Port     From             Latest
root                                       **Never logged in**
daemon                                     **Never logged in**
bin                                        **Never logged in**
sys                                        **Never logged in**
sync                                       **Never logged in**
games                                      **Never logged in**
```

I need only the fields `username` and `latest`.

How can I do that using `grep` or `awk`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The output is fixed width and number of fields aren't guaranteed so I would do:

```
$ lastlog | cut -c1-15,44-
Username       Latest
root           **Never logged in**
daemon         **Never logged in**
bin            **Never logged in**
sys            **Never logged in**
sync           **Never logged in**
games          **Never logged in**
```

Adjust appropriately for the given output of `lastlog` on your own system.

Comment: `cut` really is the tool for the job here but you could do the same thing with `awk` by using the `substr()` function i.e. `lastlog | awk '{print substr($0,1,15),substr($0,44)}'` it's just less concise.

Answer (score 1):

In principle:

```
lastlog | awk '{print $1,$4}'
```

However your last fields is separated by whitespaces so it's not considered a single field by `awk`. If you want the last part use `cut`:

```
lastlog | cut -c 1-10,40-
```

Answer (score 1):

### GNU sed

```
sed -r 's/(.{10}).{25}/\1/' file
```

..output is:

```
Username          Latest
root              **Never logged in**
daemon            **Never logged in**
bin               **Never logged in**
sys               **Never logged in**
sync              **Never logged in**
games             **Never logged in**
```